# How to distribute flutter plugin (C/C++) on iOS?

Tags: flutter, podspec, dart-ffi

I've written a plugin that calls C++ functions via `dart:ffi`. It works, that's great. In my `plugin.podspec`, I have:

```
  s.static_framework = true  # statically link my C++ files
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
```

Problem is, in the app that uses the plugin the user has to (for iOS) manually add the files to Xcode:

- open Runner.xcodeproj and click on Build Phases.
- under the "Compile Sources" add the C++ files

This is terrible user experience! I can't expect the users of my library to do this. Can this somehow avoid this? I saw [flutter/issues/17978](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17978) but I'm not sure if this is want I want here.